# how to check whether the data has been copied fram data source to ehChache

Tags: spring, ehcache

how to check whether the data has been copied fram data source to ehChache. Where will the cache get stored? inside jvm? how to check what data is stored in ehCache.

please help me out.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

> Where will the cache get stored? inside jvm?

This depends on the configuration of the cache. See the documentation for [topologies](http://ehcache.org/generated/2.9.0/html/ehc-all/#page/Ehcache_Documentation_Set%2Fco-top_topology_types.html) and for [storage tiers](http://ehcache.org/generated/2.9.0/html/ehc-all/#page/Ehcache_Documentation_Set%2Fco-store_storage_tiers.html)

> how to check what data is stored in ehCache.

You can read data from a cache, through the `get*` operations, or [query it](http://ehcache.org/generated/2.9.0/html/ehc-all/#page/Ehcache_Documentation_Set%2Fto-srch_searching_a_cache.html) if configured properly.
You can also use [cache event listeners](http://ehcache.org/generated/2.9.0/html/ehc-all/#page/Ehcache_Documentation_Set%2Fto-clst_cache_event_listeners.html) to be notified about interactions with the cache.